# R Leaflet: Assign multiple groups to a layer

Tags: r, leaflet

I am trying to draw a leaflet plot with multiple columns of categorical variables. I assign a checkbox to each group. But the checkboxes do not work fine. "A b" group includes three points, but when the checkbox "A b" is uncheck, just remove 1 point removed. Why?

```
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
groups_all<-paste(
rep(LETTERS[1:2],each=3),
rep(letters[1:3],len=6),sep="     "
)

groups_all<-paste(
rep(LETTERS[1:2],each=3),
rep(letters[1:3],len=6)
)


data <- data.frame(Name1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B"),
        Name2 = c("a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c"),
               Value1 = c(12,43,54,34,23,77,44,22),
               Value2 = c(6,5,2,7,5,6,4,3),
               Lat = c(51.1, 51.6, 57.3, 52.4, 56.3, 54.3, 60.4, 49.2),
               Lon = c(5, -3, -2, -1, 4, 3, -5, 0))


> data 
    Name1 Name2 Value1 Value2  Lat Lon
1     A     a     12      6 51.1   5
2     A     b     43      5 51.6  -3
3     A     b     54      2 57.3  -2
4     B     a     34      7 52.4  -1
5     B     b     23      5 56.3   4    
6     B     a     77      6 54.3   3
7     A     b     44      4 60.4  -5
8     B     c     22      3 49.2   0

data %>%
leaflet() %>%
addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
addAwesomeMarkers(
lng = ~Lon ,
lat = ~Lat ,
#icon = ~logos[Name1 ,Name2],
group = c(~cbind(Name1 ,Name2) ,groups_all)
            
)%>% 
addLayersControl(
#baseGroups = c(""),
overlayGroups = groups_all,
options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve with `cbind`. Instead you could simply use `paste` to create your group names from `Name1` and `Name2`.

As an example that this works I used `hideGroup("A b")` on the output which filters out all three points as desired:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

groups_all<-paste(
  rep(LETTERS[1:2],each=3),
  rep(letters[1:3],len=6)
)


data <- data.frame(Name1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B"),
                   Name2 = c("a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c"),
                   Value1 = c(12,43,54,34,23,77,44,22),
                   Value2 = c(6,5,2,7,5,6,4,3),
                   Lat = c(51.1, 51.6, 57.3, 52.4, 56.3, 54.3, 60.4, 49.2),
                   Lon = c(5, -3, -2, -1, 4, 3, -5, 0))

foo <- data %>%
  leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
  addAwesomeMarkers(
    lng = ~Lon ,
    lat = ~Lat ,
    group = ~paste(Name1 ,Name2)
    
  )%>% 
  addLayersControl(
    overlayGroups = groups_all,
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
  )

foo %>% 
  hideGroup("A b")
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a easy way to change icon size in the above code? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68172782/r-leaflet-change-size-of-icon-for-multiple-groups